# Connect to a server through tunnel like WinSCP

Tags: ssh, tunnel

I'm migrating me from Windows to Linux.
I've installed an Ubuntu (14.04.01) and I usually did this:

myPc (tunnel) -> machine A -> machine B
With the opcion "tunnel" in advanced options in WInSCP.

This way, i could upload and download files with a graphic interface (so cool)

Are there some program in Linux to do that?
Is there another way than commands in console?
Or I have to install Wine + WinSCP.

I've tried Filezilla, gFTP, konkeror...no one with "tunnel" option.

Regards and Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to first create tunnel with ssh command:

```
ssh -t -t -L 22000:127.0.0.1:22000 <user>@<machine A IP> "ssh -L 22000:127.0.0.1:22 <user>@<machine B IP>"
```

Then open file browser( eg Nautilus) and enter location:

`ssh://127.0.0.1:22000` or `ssh://<machine B system user>@127.0.0.1:22000`

Enter the user credential. Thats it.

Comment: <machine A IP> i think could be <user>@<machine A NAME> right?

Comment: If user name is different in all three servers you need to use  <user>@<machine A NAME> and <user>@<machine B NAME>

Comment: in this case result is: "Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal." I dont know if i,m doing something wrong

Comment: use `ssh -t -t` to avoid this

Comment: That WORKS! It's not like WinSCP but its a solution! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with OpenSSH but unfortunately it hasn't GUI so you have to type the commands(AFAIK). Anyway it's not a big deal and you could configure it in less than 10 minutes.

The best way would be add a configuration file for the client with all the custom directives, so you would end up only typing `ssh mydestination`. The man page for the `.ssh/config` file is [here](http://www.manpagez.com/man/5/ssh_config/).

Should look like this:

```
Host mydestination
    HostName mydestination.example.com
    Port 22
    User myusername
    LocalForward 5555 dev.example.com:5555
```

Finally to access remote files you can use the default file explorer, Nautilus. There is a 'Connect to a server' option inside the 'File' menu that allow you make remote connections. Just type the protocol and the host name you placed inside the config file:

```
sftp://mydestination
```

Comment: This will not make me  to avoid  using scp commands. :(

Comment: I added some information to my answer, hope it helps you.